# Passport.js and MongoStore error "Connection strategy not found at MongoStore"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I am getting this strange error on my Node.js server:

> ```
>  Error: Connection strategy not found
>         at MongoStore (/Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/lectal_all/manager/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:100:23)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/lectal_all/manager/app.js:42:12)
>         at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
> ```

We are using Passport with Express.

The error is happening at the line `mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection` in the following snippet:

```
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'foobar',
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        maxage: 1160000000,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    },
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection   /*<== error happens here*/
    })
}));
```

What is this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [docs](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo#re-use-a-mongoose-connection), I believe that line should be:

```
store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
});
```

Use `mongooseConnection` instead of `mongoose_connection`.

Comment: thanks, that might have done the trick, weird, this used to work, but maybe I bumped to a new version of passport/mongoose/etc

Comment: @AlexMills That might be the problem as the error is coming from the library. If there is anything, I'd be glad to help.